Create exact copy of sheet in another Excel file
I am trying to create exact copy of excel sheet in another file. I have tried using the following three methods

Cell References - Hardcoding Cell Reference in other file i.e. $A$1
VBA
Using Data Connections of PowerQuery

However, each has their own limitations

Cell References - If I add or delete a column or row, the references do not work
VBA - both the files need to be open which is not possible in our situation
Power Query - It does active data integrity but fails completely in case of formatting and do not copy the comments created in the source file

How do I go about this?
I have a deadline to meet, any guidance is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Using VBA you can Copy a worksheet from file to file.
This is how it works for me
Press Alt+F11
Sub CopySheetToAnotherWorkbook()
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    ' Update the paths and sheet names
    Dim sourceFilePath As String
    Dim targetFilePath As String
    Dim sourceSheetName As String
    Dim targetSheetName As String

    sourceFilePath = "C:\Path\To\SourceWorkbook.xlsx"
    targetFilePath = "C:\Path\To\TargetWorkbook.xlsx"
    sourceSheetName = "Sheet1"
    targetSheetName = "CopiedSheet"

    ' Open the source and target workbooks
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(sourceFilePath)
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(targetFilePath)
    
    ' Set the source sheet
    Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Sheets(sourceSheetName)
    
    ' Check if target sheet already exists and delete it if it does
    On Error Resume Next
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Sheets(targetSheetName)
    If Not targetSheet Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        targetSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Copy the sheet to the target workbook
    sourceSheet.Copy After:=targetWorkbook.Sheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    
    ' Rename the copied sheet
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Sheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    targetSheet.Name = targetSheetName
    
    ' Save and close the workbooks
    targetWorkbook.Save
    sourceWorkbook.Close False
    targetWorkbook.Close True
    
    MsgBox "Sheet copied successfully!"
End Sub

Make sure to enter the correct Paths and Sheetnames

I have a sheet that grades exam responses.
It is copied from a master file into 100 student submission files.
What I do is to make the complete sheet text, by replacing the "=" in front of every formula or function with "xyxyxy" and copying the sheet into the target workbook.
Then replace the "xyxyxy" with "=" and all the functions become live without links to to "old" source.
